# How to start sunspot solr and mailcatcher with server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every time I start my app in development I have to do this in the console:

```
$ mailcatcher
$ rake sunspot:solr:start
$ rails s
```

Is there a way to just start the server and have mailcatcher/sunspot start as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html) should do the trick for ya.